# 'socket.io error on connect: Error: xhr poll error' while importing zone.js when using Karma/Jasmine in Angular 2 with NativeScript 2.0 [1.7.1]

Tags: android, socket.io, angular, karma-jasmine, nativescript

I'm getting the below error while running my tests using Karma with Jasmine in my Angular2 with NativeScript project. The tests are being executed correctly, but, this error keeps repeating in the console. I observed the error is coming only after importing zone.js (imported it because it says zone is not defined while using inject, etc from Angular2/testing).

**Error:**

`JS: NSUTR-socket.io: transport error JS: NSUTR-socket.io: 1 JS: NSUTR: socket.io error on connect: Error: xhr poll error JS: NSUTR-socket.io: 2 JS: NSUTR: socket.io error on connect: Error: xhr poll error 04 05 2016 12:33:42.046:WARN [NativeScript / 23 (6.0; Google Nexus 6P -
6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560)]: D isconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
JS: NSUTR-socket.io: 3 JS: NSUTR: socket.io error on connect: Error: xhr poll error JS: NSUTR-socket.io: 4 JS: NSUTR: socket.io error on connect: Error: xhr poll error`

**My spec (test) file:**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone.min.js';

import {Home} from '../components/home/home';
import {inject, beforeEachProviders, it, describe, expect} from 'angular2/testing';

beforeEachProviders(() => [Home]);

describe('Home Page ActionBar Title Test', () => {
  // it('Title has text', () => {
  it('Title has text', inject([Home], (homeObj: Home) => {
      expect(homeObj.title).toBe('CapacityReview');
      // expect(true).toBe(true);
    }));
});
```

**Package.json:**

`"dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.16",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "0.0.46",
    "nativescript-intl": "0.0.2",
    "nativescript-unit-test-runner": "^0.3.3",
    "parse5": "1.4.2",
    "punycode": "1.3.2",
    "querystring": "0.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "tns-core-modules": "2.0.0",
    "url": "0.10.3",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.7.6",
    "babel-types": "6.7.7",
    "babylon": "6.7.0",
    "filewalker": "0.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-nativescript-launcher": "^0.4.0",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.1",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  }`

**karma.conf.js (default one):**
>

> ```
> module.exports = function(config) {   config.set({
>
> // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
> basePath: '',
>
> // frameworks to use
> // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
> frameworks: ['jasmine'],
>
> // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
> files: [
>   'app/**/*.js'
> ],
>
>
> // list of files to exclude
> exclude: [
> ],
>
>
> // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
> // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
> preprocessors: {
> },
>
>
> // test results reporter to use
> // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
> // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
> reporters: ['progress'],
>
>
> // web server port
> port: 9876,
>
>
> // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
> colors: true,
>
>
> // level of logging
> // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
> logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
>
>
> // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
> autoWatch: true,
>
>
> // start these browsers
> // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
> browsers: [],
>
> customLaunchers: {
>   android: {
>     base: 'NS',
>     platform: 'android'
>   },
>   ios: {
>     base: 'NS',
>     platform: 'ios'
>   },
>   ios_simulator: {
>     base: 'NS',
>     platform: 'ios',
>     arguments: ['--emulator']
>   }
> },
>
> // Continuous Integration mode
> // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
> singleRun: false   }) }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!!

After I changed the import of zone.js from

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone.min.js';
```

to

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
```

Thanks to Hristo Deshev for helping me out on this.

Comment: According to @hdeshev, another way is to replace the current imports of `zone` and `reflect-metadata` with this as the first line:
`import 'nativescript-angular/application';` which works too!

Comment: You may need to do `import 'nativescript-angular/platform';` in the more recent versions of NativeScript if importing "application" does not work for you.